# Быстрая фильтрация массива чисел js

Tags: javascript, массивы

Задача следующая: есть массив целых чисел от min до max. Необходимо получить новый массив чисел в котором каждое число будет состоять из одинаковых цифр. Например:

`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,22,33,44,55,...,1111,2222,3333]`

Я написал вот такой скрипт, но его сложность очень высокая и он работает только для массива чисел от 1 до 100 000 000. Буду благодарен, если подскажет, что я делаю не так.

```js
let arr1 = [];
let min = 1;
let max = 100000000;
for (let i = min; i <= max; i++) {
  arr1.push(i);
}

function search(arr) {
  let count = 0;
  let arr2 = [];
  let j = 0;
  let step = 1;
  let divider = 1;
  while (j < arr.length) {
    if (!(arr[j] % divider)) {
      if ((arr[j] / divider) < 10) {
        count += 1;
        arr2.push(arr[j]);
      } else {
        divider = divider * 10 + 1;
        step = step * 10 + 1;
        j = j + 1;
        count += 1;
        arr2.push(arr[j]);
      }
    }
    j = j + step;
  }
  console.log('count', count)
  console.log('arr', arr2)
}

search(arr1);
```

Comment: В смысле вам из исходного массива нужно оставить только те числа, которые состоят из повторяющихся цифр?

Comment: Да. То есть из массива [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] останутся только [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11]. Этот функционал у меня работает, но сложность моего скрипта слишком высокая, O(n), если я правильно понимаю

Comment: Но сложность фильтрации **произвольного** списка чисел не может быть меньше `O(<длина списка>)`. Вам точно нужен список? Или вам надо вернуть все числа определенного вида из заданного диапазона (а список не причём)?

Comment: Мне кажется, исходный массив  тут лишний. Зачем забивать память последовательными целыми числами?

Comment: Вообще да, мне достаточно вернуть все числа удовлетворяющие условию из заданного диапазона.

Comment: Открою вам секрет, таких чисел до 100 миллионов ровно 72 штуки. Нужно их просто заранее положить в список и потом просто проверять есть ли число в этом списке.

Comment: Начните с написания генератора -> 1, 2, ..., 8, 9, 11, 22, ..., 88, 99, 111, 222, ..., 888, 999, .... Всякое число проверяйте на попадание в диапазон. Остановитесь когда генератор выдал число большее максимума диапазона.

Comment: Я все понял, всем спасибо большое!